# Licence recommendation

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation

I am developing a software in Java and JavaFx for a local sports club (I don't get payed). I would like to grant the club all the rights for using and modifing the software as they like. Therefore I checked the Open-Source-Software-licences and thought the MIT-licence would be a good choice. But i get pretty confused, if it's possible for me to use it since my software uses some libarys with different licences (Apache License 2.0, Eclipse Public License v2.0 and Eclipse Public License v1.0).

I tried to read and understand the licences but i can't really figure out if they are compatibile or not?

Can i licence my software with the MIT-Licence when i use the libarys with the licences mentioned above? Or do you have a recommandation which licence i should use? For me it's just important that the club can use and modify the software and of course that my licencing is legal.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The licenses you mention (MIT, Apache License 2.0, Eclipse Public License 1.0 & 2.0) are all fairly permissive licenses and they are all compatible with each other. So, yes you can use the MIT license for the code you write.

The licenses that may cause a problem are the various versions of the GPL, because those licenses are not compatible with the Eclipse Public License v1.0 (EPLv1.0). This means that if you start thinking of adding a GPL-licensed library to your product, you might have to remove the EPLv1.0-licensed ones. Be aware of that.
Additionally, when you have a GPL dependency in your project, the binaries need to be released under the terms of the GPL, so it would make the licensing situation clearer if you switched your own code to GPL at that time as well.

Comment: Also, if the OP were to use a GPL-licensed library, (s)he could not release the resultant executable under the MIT licence.